# function called multiple times from template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression, angular-filters

In my template I have something like this:

```
{{formatMyDate(date)}}
```

but `date` is a scope variable that is not immediately available so this expression will call the function `formatMyDate()` many times (returning `undefined`) before returning the correct value.

I could check if the `date` is not null within the function but I guess it would be more clean NOT to call the function at all if the `date` is `null`.

Any way to achieve this?
Would a custom filter help me out here?

**EDIT:**
It was suggested that this behaviour could be normal, depending on the $digest cycle.
I've then put a `scope.$watch` to verify how many times the value of `date` is changing.
Note that I'm defining these in a directive.

```
scope.$watch('date', function(value){
  console.log('watched_date: ' + value)
})
```

and I've introduced a console.log() on my `formatMyDate` function as well

```
scope.formatMyDate = function(date){
  console.log("called_date: " + date)
  return dateService.format(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
}
```

Inspecting the console I get (pseudo code)

```
called_date: undefined
watched_date: undefined
called_date: undefined // many many times (around 20/30)
called_date: correctValue //2 or 3 times 
watched_date: correctValue 
called_date: correctValue //other 3/4 times
```

I'm wondering if this is still due to the `$digest` cycle or it is a bug in my code

Comment: Maybe a one-time binding will suit your needs, if you are on Angular >= 1.3. Check it out [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos thanks but nope, I'm forced to used the version 1.0.8

Comment: Any function called directly from an expression or indirectly through ngRepeat/ngOptions (and similar) will potentially be called multiple times. That's just how angular works (see [$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest)). That said, I think it's always a good idea to extra formatting into dedicated filters. Have you checked the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)?

Comment: @Yoshi I think this could be the problem. In this case also the filter will be called multiple times or angular is smart enough not to do that?

Comment: Yes it could be a problem, that's why there are multiple notes in the manual about keeping watchers and filters *simple* so that multiple calls won't matter much. Heavy operations should be triggered through *real* events, e.g. ngChange/ngClick. Newer versions of angular try to alleviate the problem through one-time-binding (see Nikos comment) and other optimizations.

Comment: @Leonardo Don't put tags in title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend you to do things differently:

Either use the [date `$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) or if you are doing something VERY unique and the date `$filter` is not good enough for you, then you could create your own `$filter`, like this:

```
app.filter('formatMyDate', function () {
    return function (date) {
        if (!date) return "";
        var result;
        //your code here    
        return result;
    };
});
```

And use it like this in your template:

```
{{date | formatMyDate}}
```

## UPDATE:

I guess that I didn't quite answer your question, I just gave you advice on how to improve your code. This time I will try to answer your question:

The [$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) cycle is the stage in which Angular ensures the changes of the model have settled,
so that it can render the view with the updated changes. In order to do that,
Angular starts a loop in which each iteration evaluates all the template expressions
of the view, as well as the `$watcher` functions of the `$scope`.
If in the current iteration the result is the same as the previous one,
then Angular will exit the loop. Otherwise, it will try again.
If after 10 attempts things haven't settled, Angular will exit
with an error: The ["*Infite $digest Loop Error*" (infdig)](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).

That's why the first time that the `$digest` cycle runs all the expressions are evaluated (at least) twice. And then Every time that you make a change to the `$scope` or that one of the `$watcher`s of the `$scope` gets triggered, the `$digest` cycle will run again in order to make sure that things have settled, so your expressions will be evaluated again. This is how Angular makes "data-binding" happen, it's a normal behaviour.

So in your case, when in your template you do this:  `{{formatMyDate(date)}}` or this `{{date | formatMyDate}}` you're defining Angular expressions that will be evaluated every time that the `$digest` cycle runs, which as you can imagine is very often. That's why is very important to make sure that the `$filters` (or functions) that you use in your view are efficient and stateless.

Comment: Will the filter be called multiple times until the value "stabilise"?

Comment: @Leonardo yep, in AngularJs there is data-binding, which means that when the model changes the view gets updated, since your 'date' is defined in the $scope, the $diggest cycle would detect the changes and update the view.

Comment: So basically it would be exactly the same doing this either with my solution or yours? It would be only a matter of clean code and good practise but in the end either the filter or my `formatMyDate` will be called multiple times, isn't it?

Comment: @Leonardo kind off... by creating a custom $filter you are making your code easier to re-use, easier to test and easier to maintain. Because where is your formatMyDate function defined? In the $scope of that controller, right?

Comment: @Leonardo If you are very concern about function call, you should be using `$scope.$watch` to inspect `$scope.date` property.

Comment: @RahilWazir Why in the world would you recommend the OP to do something like that? Angular is already adding a watch into all the Angular expressions of the View... So, why in the world would you do something like that?

Comment: @Josep This is how OP can prevent function calls. FYI adding watch expression won't hurt at all, it just execute user defined callback

Comment: @RahilWazir it won't help either, in a case like this it's going to be superfluous and redundant.

Comment: @Josep I completely agree

Comment: Just for experiment I did what @RahilWazir suggested putting a scope.$watch on the `$scope.date` variable and a corresponding `console.log()` when its value changes. According to this the `date` values changes only 2 times (first `undefined` then its correct value). BUT according to the `console.log()` of the `formatMyDate()` it is called 2, then 2, then 6 then 4 and so on times always being `undefined`.  Then called at least other 6/8 times with its correct values. Are we talking about the same thing here? Is it still a matter of `$digest` ?

Comment: @Leonardo Are you conditionally checking for the new value before passing it to the `formatMyDate` function? Edit your question what you tried.

Comment: @Leonardo The watcher is triggered when `date` changes, which only happens two times (transition from undefined to a concrete value). The filter/callback is triggered on every digest cycle. Angular will then check the previous results of these functions with their new results and will continue the digest cycle as long no *stable* situation, or the max digest cycle limitation, is reached. To profit from `$watch` you would need to keep the formatted date in an extra scope variable.

Comment: @Leonardo All that said, if you're really that worried about the number of function calls you should first think about [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: @Yoshi Mine is just curiosity if it is a bug coming from my side or it is just the way how angular is supposed to work

Comment: @Leonardo It probably issn't a bug but just angulars default behavior.

Comment: @Leonardo On top of Yoshi great explanations, you may want to have a look [at this graphic](http://nathanleclaire.com/images/scope-apply/digest-cycle.png), that I borrowed [from this article](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/01/31/banging-your-head-against-an-angularjs-issue-try-this/). Also, in [this post of my blog](http://sobrepere.com/blog/2014/10/14/creating-groupby-filter-angularjs/) there is a section where I give a brief explanation about how the $diggest cycle works. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who contributed with comments and answer.
@Josep I've accepted your answer, however (if you know) would you be kind to update your answer to explain this: "If in the current iteration the result is the same as the previous one, then Angular will exit the loop." The first iterations will result in the `date` variable being undefined (at least twice) so according to this logic Angular should exit the loop, but in fact it doesn't. why? maybe because we are considering that ALL the scope variables should settle and not only `date`?

Comment: @Leonardo I will as soon as I get home (5 hours approximately). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
{{date && formatMyDate(date)}}
```

will only execute the second case if the first condition exists and is different from null and undefined.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7512/