# Controller function gets called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have done some research both at Google and StackOverflow, and found several similar questions, but none seem to solve nor address my specific case. So here is my question:

In some code I am working on I am calling a controller function from my html, like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p>{{ myFunction() }}</p>
</div>
```

And since in myFunction I do some tracing, I noticed the function gets called 4 times!

I have created a minimalistic test at JS Bin, here: http://jsbin.com/nukuhemata/1/edit?html,js,console,output

In this reduced test, my function gets called 3 times (there is some progress ;-). And if instead of `{{ test() }}` I use `{{ ::test() }}` as suggested in some other answers I have seen, it gets called only twice (some more progress).

I am a beginner at Angular, from what I have read I think it is the normal, expected behavior. Is that so? If it is, why? If not, what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Could you show some more code, especially router and watchers you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's normal behavior, every time a `$digest` cycle runs, the function must be executed to check whether the output value has change, and thus whether there's a new value to update the DOM with.

Because of this, it's better practice to update a value on the `$scope` from the controller when needed, and reference that in your markup. Usually not a meaningful difference, but if your function is building up a large array for a `ng-repeat`, it can become a big deal.

Edit: See [function called multiple times from template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508564/function-called-multiple-times-from-template) for a more robust answer.

Comment: Sure, and I've run into this plenty of times myself. It's the biggest drawback to angular, it uses a lot of dirty checking, and being aware of this is important to keep apps performant. The answer to this question goes into a little more depth for the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508564/function-called-multiple-times-from-template

Comment: Thank you very much, it is a relief knowing this is normal, at first I was getting crazy. I'll have to read about the digest cycle to understand why does angular need to go through it up to 4 times.

Comment: Yeah, understanding `$apply` and `$digest` is vital for apps of any notable size. The moral of this particular question is to bind `{{test}}` instead of `{{test()}}`, and then in your controller to update `test` only when needed. It's pretty much never better to bind a function call directly, but sometimes it's a lot easier to think about.